# python requests call url which include plus character

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to call a api endpoint which looks like this
`http://api.example.com/user/jhon+doe?field=full&key=somestring`. When I call this url using python requests, I always get wrong result because of wrong user name. Here is my code

```
import requests as req
url = 'http://api.example.com/user/jhon+doe?field=full&key=somestring'
r = req.get(ur)
data = r.json() # return wrong result
print r.url # output wrong url ,, http://api.example.com/user/jhon
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you've misspelled "John"?

Comment: The + indicates a space.  Is python doing additional URL encoding/escaping/etc  ?

Comment: --jwodder , everything else are ok, except the url issue. 

@ivanivan , After some researching I have learned that requests is on top of urllib which does the encoding/ escaping I am not sure. But I can't figure out the way. Thanks

Comment: @Ali if you afraid of some escaping characters just put `r` before string: `r'http://api.example.com/user/jhon+doe?field=full&key=somestring'`